# Multimeter Measurement Problem About Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, multimeter

When i am trying to measure a 100 nF capacitor using multimeter, the value which device shows continuously increasing. Do you have an idea about the reason of this situation? Thank you. I have uploaded a video what i mentioned;

https://youtu.be/Cjw1FREHEqw

Comment: Best thing to use for capacitors is an LCR meter, rather than a multimeter

Comment: What meter are you using? There is much crap out there. Unless it is a really good multimeter I would not trust it a bit

Comment: The you tube video is not going to be there for ever. For the sake of longevity for your question can you give us a quick description of what the the you tube video shows. Type of meter, range how connected and readings.

Comment: @bieaisar: You should always provide links to the datasheets. Yours is [here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/973249/Mastech-My-60.html) but it has no circuit schematic so we don't know how the capacitance measurement circuit works.

Answer (score 1):

It is cheap low quality multimeter (according to attached video). So, problem is not in capacitor, or connections, but in multimeter itself.
Use better multimeter or even better proper LCR meter.

Take your current multimeter just as an informative rough device.

Answer (score 0):

The cap looks like a high K ceramic, X7R or worse.  They always behave a little strangely.  If you try measuring a film or C0G of the same value you probably won’t see this drift.